# Error with gradle 4.0: You cannot add child specs at execution time

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am using this configuration to build a fat jar including all dependencies, but I want to exclude some files from the dependencies:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    doFirst {
        from (configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
            exclude 'META-INF/*'
            exclude 'about.html'
        }
    }
}
```

With gradle 3.5, I get the following warning message:

> Configuring child specs of a copy task at execution time of the task has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Consider configuring the spec during configuration time, or using a separate task to do the configuration.

Since gradle 4.0, this became an error (as announced):

> You cannot add child specs at execution time. Consider configuring this task during configuration time or using a separate task to do the configuration.

How can I rewrite the `from ...` statement (the error message points to that line) to remove the error and get the desired result? Removing the exclude block fixes the error but is not what I want.

Comment: Why do you put that in a doFirst block, and not directly in the jar block, in order to do that in the configuration phase rather than the execution phase?

Comment: @JBNizet because I copied the code from somewhere ... moving it from the `doFirst` into the `jar` block indeed fixes the error! Thanks!